# Determine if two Trees are Identical

Tags: stack, binary-tree

This is the question of Binary Tree. Level: Easy
[image]

In the second code, in while loop I just stored the value of popped integer value from stack in int variables and then wrote the condition of if loop. But in first I did not stored them in any variables I directly used them in if condition of while loop. Can anyone please explain why is it creating a difference?

This was my approach, in this if the input trees are 333 and 333 then it gives "no"(trees are not identical).
`
class Solution
{

```
    public void preOrder(Node root,Stack<Integer> stack){
        if(root==null){
            return ;
        }
        stack.push(root.data);
        preOrder(root.left,stack);
        preOrder(root.right,stack);
        
    }
    boolean isIdentical(Node root1, Node root2)
    {
        // Code Here
        if(root1==null||root2==null)
        return false;
        Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> stack2 = new Stack<>();
        preOrder(root1,stack1);
        preOrder(root2,stack2);
        
        if(stack1.size()!=stack2.size())
        return false;
       
        while(!stack1.isEmpty()&&!stack2.isEmpty()){
            if(stack1.pop()!=stack2.pop())
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
        
    }
}`
```

But, in this the same input trees(333 and 333) gave correct output i.e "yes".

` class Solution
{

```
    public void preOrder(Node root,Stack<Integer> stack){
        if(root==null){
            return ;
        }
        stack.push(root.data);
        preOrder(root.left,stack);
        preOrder(root.right,stack);
        
    }
    boolean isIdentical(Node root1, Node root2)
    {
        // Code Here
        if(root1==null||root2==null)
        return false;
        Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> stack2 = new Stack<>();
        preOrder(root1,stack1);
        preOrder(root2,stack2);
        
        if(stack1.size()!=stack2.size())
        return false;
       
        while(!stack1.isEmpty()&&!stack2.isEmpty()){
            int n1 = stack1.pop();
            int n2 = stack2.pop();
            if(n1!=n2)
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
        
    }
    
}`
```

Comment: In your first code the `if` statement has an **empty** block, so it is useless. The `return` executes either way. Once that is fixed, I must tell you that the algorithm is wrong: different trees can have the same preorder sequence, so that idea wont work. But your question is about the first point, which comes down to a typo.

Comment: i mistakenly added semi-colon here on stack overflow. But in my ide i have not added semi-colon there. But the issue persists.

Comment: I used this approach because I was given that the input will be in Level Order for both the trees.